# Type error Iter - Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can someone please explain why the following code is giving

```
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'counter'  in python 3
```

This is working in python 2.7.3 without any error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class counter(object):

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size
        self.start=0

    def __iter__(self):
        print("called __iter__",self.size)
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.start < self.size:
            self.start=self.start+1
            return self.start
        raise StopIteration

c=counter(10)
for x in c:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In python3.x you need to use  [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) instead of `next()` .

from [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> [PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/): the standard next() method has been renamed to __next__().

However, if you want your object to be iterable both in python 2.X and 3.X you can assign your `next` function to the name `__next__`.

```
class counter(object):

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size
        self.start=0

    def __iter__(self):
        print("called __iter__",self.size)
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.start < self.size:
            self.start=self.start+1
            return self.start
        raise StopIteration

    __next__ = next # Python 3.X compatibility
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the `__next__(self)` not  next:

```
def __next__(self):
```